# retrieving session from uiwebview

Tags: ios, session, cookies, uiwebview, session-cookies

I'm trying to retrieving the "session cookie" that is set after I do the login to a webservice using a UIWebview. I'm able to retrieve all the cookies using NSHTTPCookieStorage, but there is no session stored. I'm wondering if cookie with no expiration date are not stored.
So Basically the scenario is the following :
1) Login using a webview
2) Do some HTPPRequest (Post) setting the cookie for those request, outside the webview.
But my problem is that the session cookie is not stored. The code below show my cookie storage policy

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]; 
[cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

Thanks in advance